# Is there an external keyboard out there that is flat, like mac keyboards, but also has macro keys?

Tags: keyboard

I'm really used to flat keys on my mac, but I want a keyboard with macros for starcraft. Anyone know of any like that?

Comment: my suggestion would be to check out various gaming keyboards. try Logitech, Saitek, Razer etc

Comment: I have been, they've all had the really big keys, that you need to push down a lot. Like... I don't want to push down 1/3 of an inch to press a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Razer and Logitech gaming keyboards are the only ones I know of that support programmable macro keys.  Razer's Arctosa has slim, laptop-style keys.  It's the only one I know of that fits your requirements.  Honestly though, the distance that you need to press the keys is probably exactly the same, even if you get a slim-style keyboard.  The only thing that changes between the two is the height of the keycaps, not the height of the key action.  Here's the Arctosa: http://store.razerzone.com/store/razerusa/en_US/pd/productID.169415000

Comment: Link is dead; here's a new one: http://www.razerzone.com/gaming-keyboards-keypads/razer-arctosa